# Artifactory OSS with Oracle defaults to Derby

Tags: java, oracle, artifactory

I recently set up a Red Hat and Oracle environment for Artifactory OSS 4.12.2. The problem is, the metadata is still being stored using Derby.

I followed the instructions at..

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+the+Database
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Oracle

I want to set it up using "DB-Filesystem - This configuration stores metadata in Oracle Database and artifact binary data is stored on the file system" Yet the Oracle database is empty and when I look at the Artifactory system info page I see...

Storage Info:
Database Type:  derby
Storage Type:   filesystem
Connection Url: jdbc:derby:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data/derby;create=true

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I really think I followed all of the instructions (tomcat/lib/obdbc7.jar, oracle.properties updated with DB connection details then copied to etc/storage.properties)

I did notice the artifactory.log file kicked off Derby on start up rather than Oracle...

2016-09-15 14:25:46,835 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.d.DbServiceImpl:186) - Database: Apache Derby 10.11.1.1 - (1616546). Driver: Apache Derby Embedded JDBC Driver 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
2016-09-15 14:25:46,836 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.d.DbServiceImpl:188) - Connection URL: jdbc:derby:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data/derby

Thanks

Jonny

**#Update 2**

```
#
#
# Artifactory is a binaries repository manager.
# Copyright (C) 2016 JFrog Ltd.
#
# Artifactory is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Artifactory is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU Affero General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License
# along with Artifactory.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#
#

type=oracle
driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@ourserver:ourport:ourdatabase
username=ourschema
password=ourschemapassword

## Determines where the actual artifacts binaries are stored. Available options:
## filesystem - binaries are stored in the filesystem (recommended, default)
## fullDb     - binaries are stored as blobs in the db, filesystem is used for caching
## cachedFS   - binaries are stored in the filesystem, but a front cache (with faster access) is added
## IMPORTANT NOTE: This property should not be change after the initial setup. To change binaries storage you have to export and import
#binary.provider.type=filesystem

## Determines the maximum filesystem cache size in bytes when using binary provider type fullDb or cachedFS. Default is 5GB
## Supported units are TB (terabytes), GB (gigabytes), MB (megabytes) and KB (kilobytes)
#binary.provider.cache.maxSize=5GB
```

**#Update 3**

This is an RPM installation on Red Hat

storage.properties is located in $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc (/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc)

The only file in the etc folder is currently storage.properties

I have restarted the Artifactory service on Red Hat after verifiting the settings in the storage.properties (settings can be found above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JonathanGraham,  can you please check the following path:
'/etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory/'
And see if the storage.properties file has the proper configuration?

Comment: Hi @Ariel that worked great. Thanks! The copy under /etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory was still using Derby. I updated the file in there and restarted the service. I can confirm that the system is now using Oracle. Should the service should have copied my file from $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc (/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc) to /etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory automatically after the original service restart?

Comment: Happy to hear that it's working now.  The etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory is the $ARTIFACTORY_HOME for RPM installation.  Therefore the file should be placed only there .

Answer (score 0):

If your Artifactory log shows that Artifactory connected to the Derby DB, then this means that you have misconfigured the $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/storage.properties file.
Would you be able to share it for further analysis? (you should of course scrub/omit any sensitive information from it).

Regards,
Itamar

Comment: Thanks for the response Itamar. I have updated the original post with a copy of our storage.properties file contained in $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc

Comment: Any idea @Itamarb ?

Comment: @JonathanGraham It seems that the configuration file is not being read by Artifactory. Additional information is required:
1. is this RPM or ZIP installation?
2. Can you make sure that the updated storage.properties file is located on $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/storage.properties?
3. can you share a screenshot of the $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/ folder? 
4. Have you restarted Artifactory after making those changes? 

I know that some/ all of the questions will look pretty basic but this is a basic procces that should work (did a quick test just now to make sure :) )

Comment: @Ariel yes, it looks like the system just isn't reading the file. Answers to your follow up questions. 1. RPM 2. Confirmed to be in /opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc 3. The only file in the etc folder is currently storage.properties 4. Yes, I restarted the service on the Red Hat box.